# Vertical align center with css pseudo classes

Tags: html, css, alignment

I've created a loading icon with css. The problem is I have to align it center in both horizontal and vertical perspectives. width of my loading animation should be `40px`. Please see the following [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/yq2hwzq8/1/)

P.S: cannot use `left:50%; top: 50%;` . Also cannot add mark-up to the html and cannot use javascript or jquery. Need a pure css solution.

updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/yq2hwzq8/9/), the pink animation section should be aligned to the center of the `div` with `class='spin'`

Comment: In which context? the viewport?

Comment: with respect to the container @hashem qolami

Comment: You looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/1v0paxzf/

Comment: no @HiddenHobbes ... I want the pink color animation to be of 40pxX40px and to be aligned to the center of 'spin' div

Comment: Ahh, so you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/nngs1167/

Comment: yes, but not allowed to use left and top values. @HiddenHobbes

Comment: May I ask why you aren't able to use top and left values?

Comment: coz in some cases I will not get the widths and heights of the parent container. @HiddenHobbes.. but the solution u gave is perfect for the current parent container resolution.

Comment: Hmm, well, I think this method is suitable even if you don't specify height and width on the parent container: http://jsfiddle.net/ek66fhtb/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71567/discussion-between-green-wizard-and-hidden-hobbes).